# Using Omnilight Yii2 Scheduling

Tags: cron, yii2, console

I have installed this extension to assist me in my cron jobs [omnilight/yii2-scheduling](https://github.com/omnilight/yii2-scheduling). The extension has good documentation that is why I settled on it amidst all the other cron-jobs extensions available for yii2. However, I am stack at some place that I need assistance. There is a place where I am asked to put a single line of code on the crontab:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/yii yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@console/config/schedule.php 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

However, I am not sure where to place it, i.e. where is the crontab in yii2? anyone who has used this extension and is able to get it running to assist me here.

Comment: No one in this forum has ever used omnilight/yii2-scheduling? I just want to get a guideline of where to place that command.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little later but you must put that in the crontab, a cron is :

> cron is a Unix, solaris, Linux utility that allows tasks to be automatically run in the background at regular intervals by the cron daemon

and the crontab is where are stored all this crons. To edit this file you must use in terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

Put that line here. Save and you are ready to go.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, thanks for your response. This is in Linux, what of windows? Does it have such utilities?

Comment: I have understood that there is a similar function on windows but i really don't use yii on windows so don't know about that. I could recommend you search for "cron in windows" and "running yii console command windows" to create a similar function.